Poetic construction - phrases placement
I am told by a friend that in English, words and phrases can be placed differently for added poetic expressions, rhythm and readability.

#1 How different has turned the promises of the lady who [...]! 
#2 The rainy evening, dark and dense.
#3 The flower, their stalks rounded.

Are these really allowed in poetry?

Yes, English grammar doesn't really apply when it comes to poetry. As long as the words can sort of be understood, it doesn't matter if grammatical rules are followed or not.

#1 should be have turned (promises are plural) and #3 should be flowers to go with their. The word order is fine.

You need full ideas. Those are just bits of sentences. And 1) is wrong.

#3 was a typo. #1 I really missed it. Thanks.

@Lambie Can you explain why it is wrong? ( I understand that it has to be have. Is anything else wrong in it?)

Kate explained it.

In the early 20th century the influential "modernist" movement had as one of its tenets the view that the syntax of poetry should be closer to that of everyday speech. So, while it is true to say that inversion is used in poetry, poets in the 20th century resorted to it far less than the poets of the 19th century did.

So, I guess you mean to say that inversion is not a popular practice today.

Contemporary poetic idiom uses inversion very sparingly.

Anything is allowed in poetry!
Forgive me if we get a little philosophical. What is language? What is the point of it?
The point of language is communication. I have a thought, and I want you to know my thought. Under most everyday circumstances, it's in my interest to make my language as clear as possible so that you understand my thought as best as possible.
This is important when we talk about "rules" of language, grammar, etc. You can say absolutely anything you want! Aside from actual real laws limiting speech, there are no consequences for saying something "wrong." Except for the consequence that you might not be well understood.
Poetry is "word art." Most of the time, the point of art is communication, too. (Most of the time.) But the difference between prose and poetry is that efficient and clear communication are no longer the priority for poetry. Often in art, the artist is content to let different people experience the art piece in different ways and draw their own conclusions. A poem can be intentionally unclear, or ambiguous, or layered with multiple possible meanings. Poetry could even be abstract, choosing words for their sound rather than their meanings!

Anything is most definitely not allowed in poetry. Even poets like EE Cummings or Lewis Carroll keep to structures that make sense.

@Lambie Perhaps we're being driven to cross-purposes by the word "allowed." I maintain that no one will revoke your "poetic license" even for artfully arranged word salads or intentional subversion of sensical structures. (The question of "why" might arise, but that's aesthetical philosophy, not language.) But I think I'll edit to address the fact that it's hard to imagine an aesthetic purpose for mismatches in number.

There are tons of things that are just not acceptable. That has or have is just a grammar mistake regardless of order which is a seperate issue.
